# Persist session after browser is closed (Spring Boot edition)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-session

This question has already been asked on SO, yet the answers were primarily using Security. I have the following constellations:

- I do not use Spring Security
- I use Spring Session JDBC

When I restart the website (as a process), the sessions persist. However, when I close and reopen the browser, the session gets closed. I have tried prolonging the cookie life:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieSerializer;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer;

@Configuration
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        // Customize the cookie
        serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
        serializer.setUseSecureCookie(true);
        serializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(true);
        serializer.setCookieMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365); // Set max age to 365 days
        return serializer;
    }

}
```

But that did not help. I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Try not using `JSESSIONID` but a different cookie.